# Safari keeps deleting items from my reading list

Tags: macos, safari, reading-list

My safari's reading list is "one shot", in the sense that if I open a URL it gets deleted, so I can just read it once. But some articles are long and I read them in 3-4 times.

I’d like manual removal only from my reading list using safari on macOS.

Is this how reading list is designed, that links disappear when you read them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're not being deleted, they're just read and you're hiding read items. Show unread items in reading list by clicking the Show Unread button above the list.

Answer (score -1):

Not true. Checked the bottom of the list immediately. The entry will be at the top once or twice, then disappears.

Comment: Could you explain a bit how this addresses the main question. This seems more a reply than an answer,  it the question could use an edit too